# NAT и HTTPS

Tags: nat, https, маршрутизатор

Здравствуйте.

Мой провайдер, видимо, накрутил у себя в HTTPS сертификатах, на сайте статистики, лишнего, от чего я стал получать (на компьютерах за NAT) сообщение от Опера "не удаётся завершить защищённую транзакцию". Нечто подобное выдает и IE, правда он еще предлагает выбрать сертификат. (Все рушится на TLS с ошибкой Handshake Failure).

Собственно у меня есть идеи, почему так, а именно из-за NAT + проверка IP по сертификату, но вот решения данной проблемы у меня нет.

NAT от iptables на CentOS.Не использовать NAT не получится.Роутер объединяет три сети (два провайдера и домашняя) плюс сеть из pptp клиентов.

Висят они, соответственно, на следующих интерфейсах:

1. Домашняя - eth0
2. Провайдер с интернетом - eth2
3. Резервный провайдер - eth1 (временно используется только как сетевые ресурсы)
4. Клиенты pptp - ppp0

Маршруты:

1. `vpn.mydomain *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0`
2. `prov1.pool     gate.prov1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1`
3. ...
4. `prov2.pool     *               255.255.192.0   U     0      0        0 eth2`
5. `default         gate.prov2 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2`

Таблица NAT:

1. `target     prot opt in     out     source               destination`
2. `MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth2    self.mydomain  anywhere`
3. `MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth2    vpn.mydomain  anywhere`

Думаю, что остальные данные из таблицы NAT не стоят внимания.

Сообщения от браузеров **UPD**:

1. FF `(Код ошибки: ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert)`
2. Opera `не удаётся завершить защищённую транзакцию`
3. Chrome сперва сказал "Сертификат безопасности сайта не является доверенным!", после кнопки "Продолжить" - `Ошибка 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): Ошибка протокола SSL.`
4. IE вообще глупый `Internet Explorer не может отобразить эту веб-страницу`

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем, проблема нашлась там, где я ее не искал.Днс сервер раньше был настроен статически, а совсем недавно я добавил в него форвард-адреса от провайдера, а статику убрать забыл. А после того, как провайдер сменил IP-адрес сервера, точнее https перевесил на другой интерфейс, вышла вот такая ситуация.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то HTTPS должен работать за NAT'ом из коробки. Скорее проблема в настройке файрволла, а не NAT'а. Еще интересно как работают другие браузеры.

Comment: С другими браузерами та же беда. В фаерволе (Маршрутизатора) у меня запреты только на tcp dpt:10000, tcp dpt:3306, tcp dpt:135, tcp dpt:143, tcp dpt:139 и tcp dpt:445. Фаерволы на компьютерах отключены. Смотрите UPD

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант: неполная цепочка сертификатов, т.е. возможно отсутствуют промежуточный и/или корневой сертификат (если сертификат покупной).